# Go: Error 550 when trying to set multiple recipients in SMTP header

Tags: email, go, smtp

I'm currently trying to send emails using the go net/smtp package. Everything but one detail works fine. I can't set multiple recipients in the email header. The Quit command returns a "550 Administrative prohibition" error. Here is my code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/smtp"
    "strings"
)

type Mail struct {
    from    string
    to      []string
    subject string
    body    string
}

type SMTPServer struct {
    host string
    port string
}

func (s *SMTPServer) serverName() string {
    return s.host + ":" + s.port
}

func (mail *Mail) buildMessage() string {
    message := ""
    message += fmt.Sprintf("From: %s\r\n", mail.from)
    if len(mail.to) > 0 {
        message += fmt.Sprintf("To: %s\r\n", strings.Join(mail.to, ";"))
    }

    message += fmt.Sprintf("Subject: %s\r\n", mail.subject)
    message += "\r\n" + mail.body

    return message
}

func Send(mail Mail, server SMTPServer) (err error) {


    // Connect to SMTP server
    c, err := smtp.Dial(server.serverName())
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // Set the sender and recipients
    if err = c.Mail(mail.from); err != nil {
        return
    }

    for _, t := range mail.to {
        if err = c.Rcpt(t); err != nil {
            return
        }
    }

    // Send the email body.
    wc, err := c.Data()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    if _, err = wc.Write([]byte(mail.buildMessage())); err != nil {
        return
    }

    if err = wc.Close(); err != nil {
        return
    }

    if err = c.Quit(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        return
    }

    return nil

}


func main() {

    mail := Mail{"a@test.com", []string {"b@test.com", "c@test.com"}, "subject", "body"}
    server := SMTPServer{"host", "port"}

    err := Send(mail, server)
    fmt.Printf("%s", err)


}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [http://nemesis.lonestar.org/site/mail_trouble.html](http://nemesis.lonestar.org/site/mail_trouble.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I looked through the provided site. However, I don't think that this is that sort of problem. I can send mails to multiple users (by calling the Rcpt function multiple times) but I can't have a "To" string consisting of multiple addresses in the email header. I have to use a single email address eventhough I send to more than one recipient.

Comment: That error comes from the MTA you're connecting to (the server you're specifying in `SMTPServer{"host", "port"}`). Check your MTA's settings (e.g. IP limits, recipient limits, etc.) and/or [teh interwebz](https://duckduckgo.com/lite?q=%22550%20Administrative%20prohibition%22). Either way, it doesn't look related to your Go code as such.